# Can't start application on Tomcat8 due to exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException?

Tags: tomcat

I copy my folder (myApp) into webapps folder of Tomcat8.

Then I went to "Tomcat Web Application Manager" & I saw "/myApp" running=false there. Then I clicked Start & found this error:

```
FAIL - Application at context path /myApp could not be started
FAIL - Encountered exception org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myApp]]
```

Before that, a guy in Youtube instructed to modify tomcat8/conf/tomcat-users.xml like this:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<tomcat-users>

  <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
  <role rolename="manager-script"/>
  <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
  <role rolename="manager-status"/>
  <role rolename="admin"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager-gui,manager-script"/>

</tomcat-users>
```

So i m not sure whether the problem is cos of the config in `tomcat-users.xml` file or something else.

Note: this is web.xml of myApp

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    version="2.5">

    <display-name>myApp</display-name>

    <!-- Default page to serve -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>myApp.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>


    <listener>
        <listener-class>myApp.server.guice.GuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <context-param>
    <!-- max size of the upload request -->
    <param-name>maxSize</param-name>
    <param-value>5145728</param-value>
  </context-param>
  <context-param>
    <param-name>slowUploads</param-name>
    <param-value>200</param-value>
  </context-param>

  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <!-- This is the default servlet, it puts files in session -->
    <servlet-class>myApp.server.SampleUploadServlet</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>uploadServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.gupld</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SimpleCaptcha</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
        myApp.server.ExtendedCaptchaServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>width</param-name>
        <param-value>200</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>height</param-name>
        <param-value>50</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>SimpleCaptcha</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/SimpleCaptcha.jpg</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

Catalina.2014-05-09.log:

```
    09-May-2014 04:52:27.290 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myApp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1780)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(Ljavax/servlet/ServletRequest;Ljavax/servlet/ServletResponse;)V" the class loader (instance of java/net/URLClassLoader) of the current class, gwtupload/server/UploadServlet, and the class loader (instance of org/apache/catalina/loader/WebappClassLoader) for interface javax/servlet/Servlet have different Class objects for the type let/ServletResponse;)V used in the signature
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2397)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1806)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5058)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 10 more

09-May-2014 04:52:27.305 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory C:\tomcat8\webapps\myApp
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/myApp]]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:702)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:697)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1134)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1780)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

09-May-2014 04:52:27.321 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat8\webapps\examples
09-May-2014 04:52:28.102 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat8\webapps\host-manager
09-May-2014 04:52:28.133 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat8\webapps\manager
09-May-2014 04:52:28.274 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\tomcat8\webapps\ROOT
09-May-2014 04:52:28.336 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
09-May-2014 04:52:28.336 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
09-May-2014 04:52:28.336 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 13386 ms
```

Comment: Take a look into your applications log file or into logs/catalina.out and post the stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your app contains a different servlet api than your Tomcat does. Check if there is a servlet-api.jar in your apps lib folder and try to remove it. If your using Maven set the dependency scope of servlet-api.jar to "provided".

Comment: i ran myAPp ok in eclipse I don't use any servlet-api.jar

Comment: i can run my app ok in Tomcat3, so it maybe something conflict

Comment: run in Tomcat 6 or 7 is  also ok